# What do elemental shields do differently from regular shields?

Tags: battlehand

It seems that they're weak to the corresponding element that a character of that element would be weak to (e.g. an air shield is weak to earth), and it even stacks with character elemental weaknesses (an air shield on an air character is *especially* weak to earth), but do they have any advantages over regular shields?